# IIS 10 ARR FARM Only Hits Second Server

Tags: iis, arr

Trying to learn IIS farming on Server 2016 - IIS 10,i'm able to configure farm setup but my ARR only get hits from second server all the time.

Here re my configuration details;
Main Server;
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.15 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it only contains one page as index.asp;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 001</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='red' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 001</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Second Server ;
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.16 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it contains the same asp page as index.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 002</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='BLUE' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 002</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Third Server ;
Windows Server 2016 Standart - 192.168.2.17 - IIS 10 - website name is servistest, it contains the same asp page as index.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage description goes here" />
  <title>Web Server 003</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
<body>
<%
  Response.Write "<font color='GREEN' size='35px'><b><center>"+FormatDateTime(date,format)+" "+FormatDateTime(time,format)+"<br>WEBSERVER 003</font></b></center>"
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are main server settings;
[image: FARM SETTING]
[image: URL RE-WRITE SETTING]
[image: LOAD BALANCE SETTINGS]

After these settings when i call 192.168.2.15 it hits to 192.168.2.16/index.asp and show this page
[image: SERVER 2 INDEX.ASP]

Refreshed page with shift+F5 multiple times, cleared browser and server's cache, no matter what i do it only shows page on Web Server 002/192.168.2.16 and never hits to main server/192.168.2.15 or third server/192.168.2.17.

On the almost all how to documents on the web, they are using domain instead of LAN IP addresses, is that what i am doing wrong? I'm working on local network that's why should i edit the hosts files of the servers and clients to work with domains? Does ARR requires at least 3 servers(main server for farm configuration +2 servers for balance) to work properly?

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed information.

Comment: @samwu oh i didn't know that, thanks for the tip

Comment: Have you checked the information from FRT?

Comment: @samwu i've enabled frt today and created some logs, you can donwload from here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hOcbIVXln1VKAaZepBK_AObJRraF8qVN/view?usp=sharing=]

Comment: Sorry, for some reasons, I cannot download these files.

Comment: @samwu sorry for that here are the alternatives;
[link]http://www.tlsteknoloji.net/iis_errlogs.zip
[link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f7ae14240b7e869a3d46c156ac99bcd220210619102935/3605e652e11012cb606844c74a8e113120210619102952/2e4789

Comment: I cannot download external files, I suggest you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to contact Microsoft support team.